# Set multiple values for custom dtype in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, dtype

I have a custom dtype which consists of two unsigned integer values:

```
dt =  np.dtype([('A', np.uint8), ('B', np.uint8)])
```

If I create a new array with the custom dtype everything works as expected:

```
>>> x = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=dt)
>>> x
array([[(0, 0), (0, 0)],
       [(0, 0), (0, 0)]],
      dtype=[('A', 'u1'), ('B', 'u1')])
>>> x[0]
array([(0, 0), (0, 0)],
      dtype=[('A', 'u1'), ('B', 'u1')])
>>> x[0,0]
(0, 0)
>>> x[0,0]['A']
0
>>> x[0,0]['A'] = 3
>>> x
array([[(3, 0), (0, 0)],
       [(0, 0), (0, 0)]],
      dtype=[('A', 'u1'), ('B', 'u1')])
```

My problem now is that for some reason I cannot set only one of the two value A and B for multiple positions:

```
>>> x[(0,1),(0,1)]['A'] = 1
>>> x
array([[(3, 0), (0, 0)],
       [(0, 0), (0, 0)]],
      dtype=[('A', 'u1'), ('B', 'u1')])
```

Anybody an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: put the field index first.  It's a view

Comment: seems to work great. thanks a lot. do you know if using custom dtypes affects performance a lot?

Answer (score 0):

As @hpaulj pointed out. The solution is:

```
x['A'][(0,1),(0,1)] = 1
>>> x
array([[(1, 0), (0, 0)],
       [(0, 0), (1, 0)]],
      dtype=[('A', 'u1'), ('B', 'u1')])
```